# Site to Site VPN between two Cisco 2921's IOS 15.2

Tags: vpn

I have two Cisco 2921's that run a site to site with static crypto maps. Everything seems pretty straightforward. Plenty of people do this. I don't have trouble with this typically. Today, the VPN just decided that it didn't want to work. I have checked over phase 1 and phase 2 in triple on both ends, I have rebuilt both routers configs from the ground up. I was running yesterday. WTH? I feel that this is just odd behavior.

They are failing on phase 1.

Anyone else have an issue like this?

Ill post my config for posterity:

```
Router-A
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key xyz address 50.xx.xx.xx   
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN_SET esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
 mode tunnel
crypto map S2S_VPN 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 description S2S VPN to Home Motors
 set peer 50.xx.xx.xx
 set transform-set VPN_SET 
 set pfs group1
 match address VPN_ACL
ip access-list extended PRC_HM_VPN_ACL
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255

Router-B
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key xyz address 206.xx.xx.xx
crypto ipsec transform-set S2S_SET esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
 mode tunnel
crypto map S2S_VPN 1 ipsec-isakmp
 description S2S VPN to Paso Robles Chevrolet
 set peer 206.xx.xx.xx
 set transform-set S2S_SET
 set pfs group1
 match address VPN_ACL
ip access-list extended VPN_ACL
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
 permit ip 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255 10.x.x.0 0.0.0.255
```

and the crypto maps applied to the appropriate outside interfaces with matching IPs

Comment: Can you show us the output of debug crypto isakmp? Plus the exact software release you're running? You might wanna upgrade to the latest stable 15.2 to avoid bug CSCuc55402 (ISM does not encrypt data (encaps counter is 0 in “show crypto ipsec sa”)) which is present in 15.2 < M6a.

Comment: I only see phase 1 key.
Where are the phase 1 configurations? hash, encryption, authentication method?

Comment: Nice note, @RedShift. Ill definitely check that out. We Run the latest M7 on router A site, router B is currently M6.

Finally, at about 3AM last night, after experiencing really, really odd behavior on the router ( i would add a default route, and it would just not show up in the routing table ), I decided to just give it another shot at rebuilding both ends entire configs and *renaming* all the profiles, ACLs, and transforms.

It just started working when I brought them back up. Frustrating having something just act so flaky. Its been in production for a year with no hiccups thus far.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I lab'd this with substitute config and I have QM_IDLE. However, Router A has an incorrect ACL name, it should be VPN_ACL as referenced in the crypto map S2S_VPN. Beyond that, I didn't have to correct any config. I also made my crypto map seq # and the policy seq # match, but this is not a requirement.

This may seem basic, but do the two routers have reachability not only at layer 3 but also layer 4 (port 500). One way to test this from the router, is to run a traceroute and count the amount of hops away it is. Now, run another traceroute, without paramaters, and in the wizard, put the correct decremented port number value so the last hop is on port 500. If it responds, the port is open, if it doesn't the port is closed. This can help you troubleshoot transit (firewall) issues. The traceroutes are UDP, but this works because isakmp is port 500 UDP.

Since, that's a confusing and I can't think of a better way to word it, visual:

```
WAN#traceroute 
Protocol [ip]: 
Target IP address: xxxxxx
Source address: xxxxxx
Numeric display [n]: 
Timeout in seconds [3]: 
Probe count [3]: 
Minimum Time to Live [1]: 
Maximum Time to Live [30]: 
Port Number [33434]: 497  <----------- If RouterB is 4 hops away the last hop will land on port 500, and you should receive a response if the port is open and you have connectivity.
```

HTH

Edit:
On Router A, these are the two values I'm talking about.

```
match address VPN_ACL
ip access-list extended PRC_HM_VPN_ACL
```

Comment: It's unrelated to the question, but for relevance to layer 4 testing, if you need to test TCP, since only UDP was mentioned in the answer; use telnet. If you receive connection refused, either the server/service isn't running or it is being blocked in transit.